# Prevent XML DoS attack in ASP.NET webmethod

Tags: asp.net, web-services, c#-4.0, denial-of-service

I have a following web method (ASP.NET, c# 4.0):

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument NewQuote(string username, string password, XmlDocument xml)
{
   // process request
}
```

I was wondering how to prevent XML DoS attack (billion laughs, external entity, etc.), as XmlDocument is accepted as a parameter? Where and how do I prohibit DTD processing? It is obviously too late in the body of the web method.

Thanks!

Comment: This is actually very good question. I believe the right answer is "don't accept XML from unauthorized users" but this I doubt this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a logic that the user can only upload x amount of files or call that service x amount of times.

Comment: Won't do. It is entirely possible to kill even the fastest server with a single 10-15 line file of XML

Comment: @Stilgar Assuming you mean a 'correctly secured server', do you have an example to back that claim up?

Comment: How about just call the method with a string instead of XmlDocument. Then if it's valid (correct username/password, still below threshold) then try to convert it to XmlDocument?

Comment: And then you can validate it with XSD

Comment: Yes I do. Save all your work (seriously!). Open your Visual Studio and crate new XML document (VS uses the .NET Load method to create an XmlDocument object for the editor to work with) and paste the XML at the end of this article http://sietch.net/ViewNewsItem.aspx?NewsItemID=173 (I am linking only because I cannot paste formatted XML in the comment). The cause of the problem is that .NET framework by default tries to expand entity references (probably to provide rich capabilities). You'll probably need to restart your computer. You can reproduce this in a simple console app that loads the XML

Comment: @ysrb:  _How about just call the method with a string instead of XmlDocument._ - I can't do that, web method is already up and running for over a year. I can not change it's signature.

Comment: @Stilgar Thanks for that! Didn't have a crash or a restart, but it definitely hung for half a minute before displaying what I'd just pasted in (VS2008 & VS2010, Win7, 8GB RAM).

Comment: Well you can easily add one more line that will cause the machine to freeze. If 1 line is not enough add 2:)

You can disable the DTD processing when loading a document and everything will be fine but the problem here is that the document is loaded somewhere in the bowels of WCF and the actual question is how you can control it.